# for loop does not continue after yield* - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that's supposed to generate a stream but then I have to loop through a list. The loop does not continue after yield*.

```
static Stream<List<Referral>> streamRefs(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> partnerLocations) async* {
    for (var partner in partnerLocations) {
      debugPrint("partner: $partner");
      yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('partners')
          .doc('kenya')
          .collection(partner['category'])
          .doc(partner['branchID'])
          .collection("referrals")
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map(((document) => Referral.fromJson(document.data(),
                  document.id, partner['branchID'], partner['category'])))
              .toList());
    }
  }
```

Comment: @pskink Yes, I'm using a StreamProvider which is working fine
The only issue is the loop not continuing so it's only returning items for the value in index 0 and yet there are three items in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `yield*` is holding your execution until the stream is completed.  And since you have an infinite stream, it will start the first one, and just stay there forever.

If you want a different behavior, you'll have to write it differently. :)

Comment: How differently?

Comment: What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: Finish the loop while generating the stream

Comment: I'm supposed to listen to changes in a Firestore subcollection, which will be a stream of data. In order to get this path, I have to loop through an array and retrieve the doc IDs from that array. I don't want to use a StreamBuilder since the are many instances I'm listening to this stream.

Comment: @kennedykaroko Why are you using `yield*`?  You end up with a finite `List`; either `yield` the `List` or iterate over each `List` element and `yield` that.